# Object variable or With block variable not set error occurring with Macro

Tags: excel, vba

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that the error occurs on the `.activate` line.

I have a simple macro set up that updates a separate document with some data. I want the the macro to automatically activate when the user saves but I am getting this error "Object variable or With block variable not set" whenever I try and use the macro.

I have the code in the `ThisWorkbook` module. I have put the code in a new module and it works fine with no errors. The error only occurs when the code is in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wbMe, wbOut As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook

    'Sets the destination for the data as well as automatically sending the data to the sheet that corresponds with the date inputted.
    Set wbOut = Workbooks.Open("/Users/MathieuKlein/Desktop/ValveStockMaster.xlsx")

    'This section deals with the actual process of copying the data and pasting it to the other excel file.
    With wbOut
        .Activate

        ' The following sets up the total of valves
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D2:H20") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro  Data").Range("K104:O122").Value
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D22:H37") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro Data").Range("K123:O138").Value
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D39:H46") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro Data").Range("K139:O146").Value
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D48:H50") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro Data").Range("K147:O149").Value
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D52:H53") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro Data").Range("K150:O151").Value
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D55:H58") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro Data").Range("K152:O155").Value
        wbOut.Sheets("Stock").Range("D61:H61") = wbMe.Sheets("Macro Data").Range("H14,H3,H5,H7,H9").Value
    End With

    With wbOut
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I expect the macro to activate when the user saves the document but this error pops up preventing that.

Comment: Seem to recall if a workbook is already open then trying to open the same workbook using workbooks.open doesn't return a reference to that workbook. Is `wbOut` set to a workbook when the `With` runs?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause this error. I do see a likely typo in `Sheets("Macro  Data")` vs `Sheets("Macro Data")` which should probably result in an error 9 Subscript out of range, but not Object variable or With block variable not set. You probably have some other code running that causes this. Get to [the exact line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687105/11683) where it happens.

Comment: The `Range("H14,H3,H5,H7,H9")` union is not delivering the values in that order (if at all).

Comment: You can't use .Value on a multi-area range

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. `Workbooks.Open` either returns a reference or throws an exception. It does not seem to matter if the workbook already opened, it returns a reference anyway.

Comment: I have edited the question to include where the error occurs. 

@TimWilliams I set the workbook before the With runs. Also, if I can't use .Value on a multi-area range, why does it work when not in the "ThisWorkbook" module?

Comment: Maybe check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169301/vba-workbook-openfile-returns-nothing

Comment: Unrelated but instead of `Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook` you should use `Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your path separator (slash or backslash):

```
Debug.Print "Application.PathSeparator: ", Application.PathSeparator
```

Please try if it's already open and otherwise try to use a full path.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wbOut = Workbooks("ValveStockMaster.xlsx") ' already open?
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error Goto 0
    ' use full path:
    Set wbOut = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MathieuKlein\Desktop\ValveStockMaster.xlsx")
    ' ...
End If
On Error Goto 0
' ...
```

Please declare like this:

```
' instead of Dim wbMe, wbOut As Workbook
Dim wbMe As Workbook, wbOut As Workbook
```

If it's later not put on someone's desktop, try to concatenate with one of these paths e. g. like `Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Test.xlsx"`

```
Debug.Print "ActiveWorkbook.Path: ", ActiveWorkbook.Path
Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.Path: ", ThisWorkbook.Path
Debug.Print "Application.DefaultFilePath: ", Application.DefaultFilePath
Debug.Print "Application.RecentFiles(1).Path: ", Application.RecentFiles(1).Path
Debug.Print "Path: ", Application.Path
Debug.Print "LibraryPath: ", Application.LibraryPath
Debug.Print "StartupPath: ", Application.StartupPath
Debug.Print "AltStartupPath: ", Application.AltStartupPath 
Debug.Print "AutoRecover.Path: ", Application.AutoRecover.Path
Debug.Print "TemplatesPath: ", Application.TemplatesPath
Debug.Print "UserLibraryPath: ", Application.UserLibraryPath
```